# Uncaught TypeError: Object(…) is not a function BnNgIdleService in angular?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, angular-material

In angular 7.2.4, trying to to display login page after compiling and running the project. While starting localhost:4200/#/login it gives the following error in the console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    BnNgIdleService bn-ng-idle.js:79
    js bn-ng-idle.js:81
    Webpack 14
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.0",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.1"
       },
```